# how to get matrix itens by a count variable <? @entity[$count].literal ?> in Watson assistant (conversation)

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I need to get all user input literals from a entity array. For example,

**The user input:**

I want to see dolphins, an elephant and dogs

**The entity:**

`{
"type": "synonyms",
"value": "animalcheck",
"synonyms": [
"dolphins",
"elephant",
"dogs",
"dog",
"dolphin",
"girafe"
]
}`

So.. need the user inputs literal: ["dolphins","elephant","dogs"]

I'm trying with this:

`<? @entity[$count].literal ?>`

where $count=1 and will be incremented until reach @entity.values.size() but this $count inside brackets return error, it's not works.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you want to do. What is the user message, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I do say you seem to be making hard work for yourself. Is there any reason you cannot have an entity group that's its own list of animal types, i.e. animals, which itself contains the values ["dolphins","elephant","dogs"]. In this way, if a users question contains any of these values, they will be in the entity array animals:["dolphins","dogs"] etc.

Which in turn is easier to handle within assistant. There is nothing to stop you having both entity groups "animals" and "animalcheck". 
(Although animalcheck seems to be your value, not sure what your entity is actually called. You example uses @entity - but sure that would be allowed as an entity name. ) 
Also to access your entity, say if it was called "entitylist", you would need to use; 
 
See Docs; https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the `$count` variable not being treated as an integer and only integer can be used to access an array in `WA`.

This expression will assure that the content of `$count` variable will be treated as an integer and hence be ok to access arrays in WA:

`<? @entity[$count.toInt()].literal ?>`.